# Store bitmap image in Firebase android

Tags: android

I have a problem. I am making an app with backend firebase and i want to save the image in firebase. Is there any way to store the bitmap images in Firebase. I didn't get  the right tutorial.. Please help.

here is code where I get the images and want to save that images in Firebase

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                mImageCapture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                mTextImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            mImageCapture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            mTextImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code where I save the name , phone no and location in Firebase

```
    if(isOnline()){
                User myData = new User();
                myData.setUsername(name);
                myData.setPhoneno(phone);
                myData.setLocation(location);
                ref.child("DataBase").push().setValue(myData);
                Toast.makeText(BasicInformation.this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(BasicInformation.this, HomePage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }else{
                openDialog();

            }
```

Comment: Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Comment: Thanks for your response @Raghunandan  I am new to Firebase database so can you please explain.. for the storage we have a library to import??

Comment: You can look into this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start

Comment: can you show me some example ? I am unable to do it

Comment: The Firebase docs are very good at explaining this, but make sure you get the new docs, not the old versions - they are marked at the top of each page where they are deprecated.

Comment: Do you still need help?